# Calling exec returns errno 14 (bad address) with absolute path

Tags: unix, cgi, exec, fork

in making a simple cgi server for a course. To do that in some point I have to make a fork/exec to launch the cgi handler, the problem is that the exec keep returning errno 14. I've tried the following code in a standalone version an it works with and without the absolute path.

Here's the code:

```
static void _process_cgi(int fd, http_context_t* ctx)
{
    pid_t childProcess;
    int ret;
    char returnValue[1024];
    log(LOG, "calling cgi", &ctx->uri[1], 0);

    if((childProcess = fork()) != 0)
    {
        ///
        /// Set the CGI standard output to the socket.
        ///
        dup2(fd, STANDARD_OUTPUT);
            //ctx->uri = "/simple.cgi"

        execl("/home/dvd/nwebdir/simple.cgi",&ctx->uri[1]);
        sprintf(returnValue,"%d",errno);

        log(LOG, "exec returned ", returnValue, 0);
        return -1;
    }

    ret = waitpid(childProcess,NULL,0);
    sprintf(returnValue,"%d",ret);
    log(LOG, "cgi returned", returnValue, 0);
}
```

Here is the list of sys calls that the server passes before reaching my code (in order):
- chdir
- fork
- setpqrp
- fork
I don't know if this is relevant or not, but in my test program I don't have chdir nor setpqrp.

The test code is the following:

```
pid_t pid;

    if ((pid = fork()) != 0)
    {
        execl("simple.cgi","simple");
        //execl("/home/dvd/nwebdir/simple.cgi","simple");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("waiting\n");
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    printf("Parent exiting\n");
```

Note I've tried both execl and execlp in the server code.

You can find the basic server implementation (without CGI) in here, the only changes I made was in the web funcion:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-nweb/index.html

Regards

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
execl("simple.cgi","simple", NULL);
```

The null is needed because execl() is a varargs - function.

Comment: That did the trick, but why did it work on the test version and not in the server version?

Comment: Invoking undefined behaviour leads to undefined (read erratic) behaviour, including sometimes appearing to work.

Answer (score 7):

```
    execl("/home/dvd/nwebdir/simple.cgi", &ctx->uri[1], (char *)0);
```

The last argument to `execl()` must be a null `char *`.  You can usually get away with writing `NULL` instead of `(char *)0`, but it might not produce the correct result if you have `#define NULL 0` and you are on a machine where `sizeof(int) != sizeof(char *)`, such as a 64-bit system.

Comment: The *reason* for the explicit cast being necessary is that normally the compiler can infer the length of the parameter to put on the stack from the function prototype. However, in this case, the last pointer is part of a list of variable arguments (`...` in the prototype) and thus the compiler will just push an `int` when it sees a `0`. The `execv()` function does not exhibit this problem because it is passed an array `char * const argv[]`.

Answer (score 3):

BTW, either you copied the code incorrectly or it has logic error. Fork() returns non-zero to parent process, not child one, so condition shall be reverted. (There is no comment button here so making answer.)